# Как настроить при запуске приложения открытие двух портов c# asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, kestrel

В общем есть WebAPI, в нем реализовано rest-api, так же создан .proto, и по нему реализован сервис gRPC.
После этого мне нужно, чтобы при запуске приложение открывало два порта. Один для gRPC, второй для REST-апи. Так же нужно настроить так, чтобы доступ к gRPC был только с одного порта, и чтобы по этому порту нельзя было получить доступ к rest-апи.
Я не понимаю как мне вообще настраивать порты, знаю что нужно использовать Kestrel, но не понимаю с чего начать.

Comment: А зачем обычный REST, когда есть gRPC?

Comment: @aepot это как этап обучение, задание. Я просто не понимаю как это сделать

Comment: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70817994/5045688), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-8.0)